# Registered CellInfo?

Tags: android

The official android documentation said that the getAllCellInfo() method,  which is responsible of returning all observed cell information from all radios on the device including the primary and neighboring cells, returns valid data for ***registered cells*** on devices with FEATURE_TELEPHONY.
My problem is that only the first cellInfo (I suppose the one my phone is connected to) returns true when calling CellInfo.isRegistered(). what is a registered CellInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registered Cell is the Network Cell that your device is actually registered to.

Neighboring cells just shows a list of neighboring cells which are being monitored by the device. However, device is not registered to them.

It must track those cells and measure its signal levels since it may need to move to a better cell - with better signal quality, for example).

So, I believe it is normal return `isRegistered() == true` only for primary cell.

Comment: I just found out that : At most two cells could be registered, probably for double sim phones. Thank you